# Prevent new window opening at Internet Explorer bookmarks toolbar

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

There is a computer with Internet Explorer 8, Tabs are disabled completely.

When the bookmarks on bookmark toolbar is clicked, they are opened in a new window. The need is; they should open in the current window.

Note that, bookmarks menu works as expected and opens bookmarks in current window, the same is needed on bookmarks **toolbar**. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this setting here, make sure it is checked:

> Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Browsing - Reuse windows for launching shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: I first tried that setting, but when tabbed browsing is disabled, that option does not change anything, they all open in new windows. When tabbed browsing is enabled, bookmarks from the toolbar open in  new tabs.  I tried restarting IE after each change.